# Calculate pi in prolog recursively with Leibniz formula

Tags: recursion, prolog

I want to learn some prolog and found the exercise to calculate pi recursively for a given predicat pi(10, Result). I don't want it to be tail recursive because I find tail recursion to be easier. I've been trying to do this for hours now but it seems like I can't come to a solution, this is how far I've come:

(I'm using Leibniz' pi formula as reference)

```
pi(0, 0).   
pi(Next, Result) :-
    Num is -1**(Next + 1),
    Part is Num / (2 * Next - 1),
    N1 is Next -1,
    pi(N1, R),
    Result is Part + R.
```

Now, I'm aware that the addition at the end is wrong. Also I need to multiply the end result by 4 and I don't know how to do that. Would be glad if anyone could help out. And no, this is not a homework or anything. :)

Comment: I didn't examine your code for the correct formula (I assume you can do that). But, you need a test in your recursive clause that makes it exclusive of the base case. Something like `Next > 0` and/or `Result > 0` or whatever the requirement is for that case. Also, since you're dealing with floating point numbers, you can't seek to precisely `0` in the base case. You're going to need to use an interval (epsilon) around `0.0` to check for. Otherwise, you may never match it.

Comment: If you want to recursively perform an operation, then in the end multiply by 4, use a separate predicate. Your `pi` becomes `pi_over_4`. Then create `pi(P) :- pi_over_4(..., R), P is R * 4.`.

Comment: FYI, `Resultant` ==> `Result`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint with the multiplication by 4. I do match the base case every time though. :) Here's is the formula by Leibniz (at the end of proof section): [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) My variable `Next` stands for k in the formula. Since k is a natural number, it will always become 0 at some point. :)

Comment: FYI Prolog does let you have more complex expressions, such as, `Part is Num / (2*Next - 1)` so you don't need `Sub` or `Denom`.

Comment: I see. The first argument of the base case matches because it's an integer and the second isn't matched but instantiates a variable, so yeah, that works. `Num is -1**Exponent` may be overkill just to get the sign of the term. You could either just check the bit and do `-> ;` (if-else), or include an alternating -1/1 multiplier argument that you carry along each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly different twist that terminates based upon reaching a given precision. It also is tail recursive. Because Leibniz converges very slowly, the formula is a stack hog when done using simple recursion. it's not an algorithm well-suited for a recursive solution in any language. However, a smart Prolog interpreter can take advantage of the tail recursion and avoid that. Just by way of example, it only allows precision within a specific range.

```
pi(Precision, Pi) :-
    Precision > 0.0000001,
    Precision < 0.1,
    pi_over_4(1, 1, Precision/4, 1, Pi_over_4),  % Compensate for *4 later
    Pi is Pi_over_4 * 4.

pi_over_4(AbsDenominator, Numerator, Precision, Sum, Result) :-
    NewAbsDenominator is AbsDenominator + 2,
    NewNumerator is -Numerator,
    NewSum is Sum + NewNumerator/NewAbsDenominator,
    (   abs(NewSum - Sum) < Precision
    ->  Result = NewSum
    ;   pi_over_4(NewAbsDenominator, NewNumerator, Precision, NewSum, Result)
    ).


2 ?- pi(0.0001, P).
P = 3.1416426510898874.

3 ?- pi(0.00001, P).
P = 3.141597653564762.

4 ?- pi(0.000005, P).
P = 3.141595153583494.
```

This is strictly an imperative use of Prolog, which isn't what Prolog is strong for.